Removing draggable from component on drag not working (React DnD)
Whenever I drag a different YV_Class component into a YV_Quarter that has already had a class dragged into it, the class that was already inside the YV_Quarter gets removed. enter image description here
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { removeCourse, YV_DataContext } from './YV_DataContext.jsx';
import { useContext } from "react";

// num: ELEC_ENG 195-0
// name: Special Topics in Electrical Engineering

export default function YV_Class({ id, year, semester, num, name }) { // add id
    const testData = useContext(YV_DataContext);

    const [{ isDragging }, drag, dragPreview] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: 'COURSE',
        item: () => {
            return {item, num, name};
        }, // issue: the num and name don't change on new drag
        isDragging: () => {
            if (year && semester) {
                removeCourse({"num": num, "name": name});
            }
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
        })
    }));

    return (
        <div ref={dragPreview} style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
            <div 
                // role="Handle"
                ref={drag}
                className="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-4"
            >
                <p>{num}</p>
                <p>{name}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";

import { addCourse } from './YV_DataContext.jsx';
import YV_Class from "./YV_Class";


// on drop, remove course from previous location
// how to store previous location (year, semester)? 
    // 

// courseList: [{num, name}, {num, name}... ]
export default function YV_Quarter({ year, semester, courseList }) {

    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: 'COURSE',
        drop: (course) => {
            addCourse(year, semester, course);
        },
        canDrop: (item) => {
            for (let i in courseList) {
                if (courseList[i].num === item.num) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isOver: monitor.isOver()
        })
    }));

    return (
        <div 
            ref={drop}
            role={'Dustbin'}
            style={{ backgroundColor: isOver ? 'red' : 'white' }}
            className="container p-3 m-auto h-auto flex flex-col gap-4 bg-yellow-400"
        >
            {
                courseList.map((course, i) => (
                    <YV_Class key={i} id={course.id} year={year} semester={semester} num={course.num} name={course.name}/>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

import { createContext } from "react";
import fourYearPlan from '../assets/four-year-plan.json';


let planData = fourYearPlan;
const YV_DataContext = createContext(planData);

// year: string ("2022-2023")
// semester: string ("FALL", "WINTER", "SPRING")
// course: object ({num, name})
function addCourse(year, semester, course) {
    planData[year][semester].push(course);
}

function removeCourse(course) {
    iterate(planData, course);
}

function iterate(obj, course) {
    // console.log(`course: ${JSON.stringify(course)}`);
    let objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

    loop: for (let i in objKeys) {
        
        let key = objKeys[i];
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key] !== null) {
            iterate(obj[key], course);
        }

        else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            for (let item of obj[key]) {console.log(item)};
            const courseIndex = obj[key].findIndex((arrCourse) => {
                return arrCourse.num === course.num;
            });
            console.log(courseIndex);
            if (courseIndex > -1) {
                obj[key].splice(courseIndex, 1);
                break loop;
            }
        }

    }
}


export {
    YV_DataContext, addCourse, removeCourse
}

YV_Classes dragged from here:
import { useState } from "react";
import YV_Class from "../years-view/YV_Class";
import courselist from "../assets/class-list.json";

// courseList: [{num, name}, {num, name}... ]
const searchCourseList = courselist.map((course) => (
    {
        num: `${course["SUBJECT"].toUpperCase()} ${course["CLASSDESCR"]["CATALOG_NBR"]}`, 
        name: course["CLASSDESCR"]["COURSE_TITLE"]
    }
))

export default function CourseSearch() {
    
    // querying
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");    
    function handleQuery(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    }
    

    // code for sorting
    /*
    const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
        const { active, over } = e;

        if (active.id !== over.id) {
            setdraggableIDs((draggableIDs) => {
                const oldIndex = draggableIDs.indexOf(active.id);
                const newIndex = draggableIDs.indexOf(over.id);

                return arrayMove(draggableIDs, oldIndex, newIndex);
            });
        }
    }
    */

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mt-5 grid grid-rows-[5%,95%] gap-3">
                <div className="">
                    <input 
                        name="classSearch"
                        placeholder="Search for a class..." 
                        value={query}
                        onChange={handleQuery} 
                        className="w-full"
                    /> 
                </div>
                
            
                <div className="bg-red-400 pt-3 flex flex-col gap-4 no-scrollbar overflow-auto">
                    {searchCourseList.map(({ num, name }, id) => {
                        if (num.includes(query.toUpperCase())) {
                            return (<YV_Class key={id} num={num} name={name}/>);
                        }
                        else { return null }
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

I think the issue is with YV_Class, since I fire the removeCourse() function inside isDragging, but num and name remain the same across different YV_Classes when dragging for some reason. Not sure though.
